# Github - create feature branch off a release branch on desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm trying to create a feature branch off of a release branch using Github desktop (windows) and Github in browser. My issue is, whenever I try to create a new branch based on my release branch, it makes the new feature branch off of the master.

So how do I simply create a feature branch BELOW the release? Or do I even need to have it below? I'd like to stay away from command line.
[screenshot of my current Git network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz2K6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be in the branch from which you want to branch-out when creating a new branch. So in the command line.

```
git checkout <branch that you want to use as base>
git pull
git checkout -b <new feature branch name>
```

Comment: @beavertrapper07 `git` command line does have a learning curve to it, but once you have the basics there is a lot more help out there (because almost all examples use the command line). And there is lots you can *only* do from the command line.

Comment: @beavertrapper07 Whatever software you are using must have functionality to perform these operations for you. So the steps are the same: checkout the desired base branch, pull this branch, create new branch from it. Personally, I do very few things from interfaces, because sometimes I am not sure what they are doing in the background, so at least these basic commands I would suggest you to get familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly *all branches are equal* in git. There is no sense of a branch off another: an existing branch is just a way to identify a commit.

Secondly when creating a branch without an explicit starting ref the current `HEAD` is used (ie. the latest commit of the current branch).

But you can just specify another ref when creating the branch:

```
git branch newBranchName ref
```

Comment: @beavertrapper07 Why?

Comment: @JakeD mainly so I can delegate this to peeps with no experience outside of Excel lol

Comment: @beavertrapper07 I see...you can always make a simple GUI application in, e.g., Python that runs a few command line Git commands.

Comment: I think I'm overthinking it @JakeD; when I use the commands that everyone suggests, I get the same output. So maybe I'm just hung up with the graphic of the feature branch being above the release branch and not below it.

Comment: @beavertrapper07 see the first sentence of this answer! (Even `master` is just a default, it is only special in being created when a repository is initialised.)

Comment: @beavertrapper07 It seems like you might be referring to the visualization of your branches. You actually need to have a commit on a branch in order for it to look "separate" for most visualizations. The bottom line is that this doesn't even matter, which is I think what Richard is trying to explain to you. A branch simply points to a reference (e.g., a commit).